# getelement by ID angular

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, typescript, angular7

I use asp.net and angular 7 and I try to recover data saved by a form with a get ID the data they are well stored in local storage but it’s not displayed in the front-end of user and there is not an error that displays can you help me
in the component i have this code

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  Syntheses: AddClient[];
  currentSynthese: AddClient;
  currentSyntheseSubscription:Subscription;
  public currentSyntheseSubject: BehaviorSubject<AddClient>;
  
getByIdSynthese(idSynthese:number){
  this.userService.getByIdSynthese(idSynthese).toPromise().then(res =>this.currentSynthese= res as AddClient);
}
```

in the HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.Date}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCD01}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCD02}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCD03}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCD04}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCD05}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCI01}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCI02}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCI03}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCI04}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MCCI05}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACD01}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACD02}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACD03}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACD04}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACD05}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACD06}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACI01}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACI02}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACI03}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACI04}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACI05}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MACI06}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MOCD01}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MOCD02}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MOCD03}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MOCI01}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MOCI02}}</td>
    <td>{{currentSynthese.MOCI03}}</td>
</tr>
```

and in the service this code

```
getByIdSynthese(idSynthese: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.rootURL+`/AddClients/${idSynthese}`);
}
```

Comment: console log res, what does it give you?

Comment: Where do you call `getByIdSynthese()` ?

Comment: no error message or resultin the console log

Comment: i call getbyIdSynthese in the component

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this in your service:

```
async getByIdSynthese(idSynthese: number): Promise<AddClient> {
    const result = await this.http.get(this.rootURL+`/AddClients/${idSynthese}`);
    console.log(result);
    return Promise.resolve(result);
}
```

and in your component:

```
async getByIdSynthese(idSynthese:number){
    this.currentSynthese = await this.userService.getByIdSynthese(idSynthese);
    console.log(this.currentSynthese);
}
```

First, I think it's a little bit cleaner, then, it might just avoid confusion on where the data is returned wrongly.

Comment: hello, I used this code but there’s an error I don’t know how to fix it if you can help me..
 ERROR in src/app/_services/user.service.ts:35:9 - error TS2740: Type 'Observable<Object>' is missing the following properties from type 'AddClient': IdSynthese, Id, user, Date, and 37 more.
    
    35         return Promise.resolve(result);
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: This is a type error. It means that the `const result` is not defined as type AddClient. Please add the type as follows `const result: AddClient = etc....`